# Avoiding a NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net

I have used this code for extracting urls from web page.But in the line of 'foreach' it is showing

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

exception.  What is the problem? how can i correct that?

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=java&start=10&sa=N";
string source = client.DownloadString(url);
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(source);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href and @rel='nofollow']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should look up the [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) in the documentation. It says

> The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference.

This means you did the equivalent of

```
SomeClass reference = null;
reference.Method(); // or reference.Property;
```

Next, look at the line of code that has the error and figure out what you are derefencing:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href and @rel='nofollow']"))
```

- `doc.DocumentNode`
- `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes`

So either `doc` is null, or `doc.DocumentNodes` is null. Since you just assigned a new instance of `HtmlDocument` to `doc`, `doc` can't be the problem. That implies that you loaded an empty document, such that there is no `doc.DocumentNode`.

Check before the loop to see if `doc.DocumentNode` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Which line is the exception being thrown from; the actual `foreach` line, or the contents of the loop?

Probably the easiest method to deal with this one is to use the debugger - pop a breakpoint in front of the `foreach`, and when the runtime pauses, inspect the contents of the various variables, such as `link`, `doc.DocumentNode`, etc. If `link` is non-null, then check whether `link.Attributes["href"]` is, and so on.